# Behaviour of copy constructor accepting const reference

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

In the following Code, in this line

> A(A& b)

When using this compiler gives error as

c110.cpp:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A(A)’

c110.cpp:8: note: candidates are: A::A(A&)

But as soon as i convert it into

> A(const A& b)

Many many thanx in Advance

No error comes. Why is it so?

```
Code
class A
{
    public: 
    static int cnt;
    A(A& b)
    {
       cnt++;
       cout<<"cnt="<<cnt<<endl;
    }
    A()
    {
       cnt++;
       cout<<"cnt="<<cnt<<endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
       cnt--;
       cout<<"cnt="<<cnt<<endl;
    }
};



  int A :: cnt=0;


  A fun(A b)
  {
  return b;
  }


 int main()
 {
     A a;
     A b=fun(a);
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Non-`const` references cannot bind to temporaries. If you pass a temporary as parameter, `A&` is illegal but `const A&` isn't.

The line

```
A b=fun(a);
```

does copy-initialization on the object returned by `fun(a)`, which is a temporary.

Also, the copy constructor *shouldn't* take a non-const reference because, logically, you don't need to modify the object you're copying from.

Comment: But in C++ functions instead of creating temporary when returning values the address of the b is passed and it is copy-constructed with the b variable inside function

Comment: I think it is RVO(Return Value Optimization), wouldn't it take place here??

Comment: @Luv it can and probably will. But it doesn't matter. Just because it doesn't use something doesn't mean it doesn't have to be properly defined.

Comment: It's not clear, Is RVO optimization taking place here? I think no else why would the temporary would be created

Comment: @Luv the compiler is free to omit any extra copies it can. But it still needs to have access to the methods. Best way to find out is to put debug statements in your code.

Comment: You mean to say its compiler dependent. But i think RVO is not taking place here.If it would have then the address of the object to which the value is to be returned would have been passed into the function as paramater, no temporary creation and object would have copy-constructed inside the function itself.

Comment: @Luv I'm saying optimizations don't affect the validity of a program. If a copy constructor or whatever must be visible, it must be visible, regardless of whether it's called or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think its always safe to use A(const A&) type of syntax for copy construction rather than A(A&), because RVO may take place or not, its compiler dependent.

As in the above question RVO is not taking place and the temporary is been created, hence A(const A&) is safe to use.

Comment: It *doesn't matter* if RVO is taking place. Like other optimizations, it will *never* affect the validity of a program, regardless of compiler.